# Google Cloud Function endpoint blocked in Iran

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have an endpoint deployed in google cloud function to perform a microservice for my website. However, I noticed that our users from Iran are not seen in this microservice.

I have done some reading about US sanctions. Is it possible that Google is blocking users from Iran from access services in GCP (such as a HTTP endpoint built in Google Cloud Function)?

Or is Iran ISPs censoring Google services?

Answer (score 1):

Even if this [document](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2891389?hl=en) is specific for Gsuite the restrictions of countries that cannot access Google services due [US Embargoed Countries Policy](https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/sanctions/Programs/Pages/iran.aspx) that includes Iran are present for various other Google’s products. This means that restrictions in the service may affect for this country.